# Marklogic:First request to marklogic takes time

Tags: marklogic

I have a simple code in my `XXX.xqy` to save document in **Marklogic**.
First request to save always takes more time than subsequent request.

I tried to use `trace()`, it shows saving is done in less than 1ms, but to complete request it takes time.

I just has `xdmp:document-insert()` statement in my `XXX.xqy`.

we can see the same result in jmeter load test, first request takes time around 600ms than it drops to 3-6 ms.

Does ML compiles code first time?
Is there any way to **precompile** the code?

Comment: Without posting a sample of your code that reproduces the problem, I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of the module cache. The first time you run a module it will compile the module. There is a life time on the cache too see https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-set-module-cache-timeout

Comment: I am not importing any module. I just have below statements in abc.xqy: xdmp:document-insert($uri, xdmp:get-request-body()/node()) .... the first request takes time(500ms+) after that it takes 10ms around to complete insertion. if i insert after around 125 seconds It again takes 500 ms. Looks like there is some cache for this code which gets cleared after 125 sec. I even tried to modify value for "module cache timeout" from admin screen to 2 second, but then also same result.

Comment: The cache timeout should be much higher than 125 seconds. Is the document you are inserting the same one for each request? same uri same value?

Comment: Its new document always, new uri.

Comment: at this point i'd still say modules cache. what is it set at?